# export looped numpy histogram outputs to list without array information and formatting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, histogram, tolist

I am running through a loop of data compiled from a number of lists. I am eventually going to create a histogram, however I want the binned outputs from the histogram function to be exported to a list. Currently, the data is exported a list, that looks like an array - I assume this is coming from the original output from numpy, but I can't seem to solve the issue. What I want ideally is the binned values for each sub-list without the information about the array and the binned headers - any pointers?

```
bins = [0, 1.06, 5.01, 10.01, 15]
sigmafreqdist=[]

for i in alldata:
    freqdist = np.histogram(i,bins)
    sigmafreqdist.append(freqdist)


#print the list 
print(sigmafreqdist)
```

The result I get is something like this:

```
(array([ 6, 14,  2,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ])),
 (array([ 5, 14,  0,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ])),
 (array([31, 19,  2,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ])),
 (array([12, 43,  1,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ])),
 (array([30, 34,  1,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ])),
 (array([12, 13,  0,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ])),
 (array([12, 28,  1,  0], dtype=int64),
  array([ 0.  ,  1.06,  5.01, 10.01, 15.  ]))]
```

The first array is useful, but the rest isn't any good - plus the text and brackets are not required. I have tried np.delete np.tolist to no avail

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am quite new - sorry if the code is inefficient!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first answer to a stackoverflow post. Instead of using 'for loops' try and use the simpler 'list comprehension'. I hope this helps you!

```
import numpy as np

# Random dataset. Create a list of 3 lists. Each list contains 20 random 
# numbers between 0 and 15.
Data = [np.random.uniform(0,15,20) for i in range(3)]

# Values used to bin the data.
Bins = [0, 1.06, 5.01, 10.01, 15]

# Using np.histogram on each list.
HistogramData = [np.histogram(i,Bins) for i in Data]

# 'i[0]' selects the first element in the tuple output of the histogram 
#  function i.e. the frequency. The function 'list()' removes the 'dtype= '.
BinnedData = [list(i[0]) for i in HistogramData]

print(BinnedData)

# Merging everything into a definition
def PrintHistogramResults(YourData, YourBins):
    HistogramData = [np.histogram(i,YourBins) for i in YourData]
    BinnedData = [list(i[0]) for i in HistogramData]
    print(BinnedData)

TestDefinition = PrintHistogramResults(Data, Bins)
```